# замена одинаковых символов(строки)

Tags: c, visual-studio, строки

```
#define CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int k, i;
    char str[100];

    scanf("%s", &str);
    for (i = 0, k = 1; str[i] != 0; i++)

        if (str[i] == str[i + 1]) k++;

        else {

            if (k > 1) 

            printf("%s", str[i]);


        }

    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте.
Нужно заменить подряд идущие одинаковые символы - одним символом, напр: 
я там набросал кое-что, но код не проходит ни один тест (0/16)
    fhdhhhh=fhdh;

Вот эту часть задания, к сожалению я не знаю как выполнить:   Строку необходимо считать в память целиком и произвести все манипуляции по удалению символов в памяти, а затем распечатать получившийся в памяти результат.

Comment: Рады за вас, что у вас все так хорошо и работает. Вы же просто хотели поделиться достижением?

Comment: нет, я изменил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        while (str[i+1] == str[i]) ++i;
    }
}
```

На исправленный вопрос, обидевшись на замену задания на ходу :) - вот, работает, но работает **неэффективно**:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        while(str[i+1] == str[i])
        {
            int j = i+1;
            while(str[j] = str[j+1]) ++j;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

Подумайте, как изменить код так, чтоб было эффективно, и исправьте самостоятельно.

А если вы еще раз измените вопрос - решайте тогда сами... :(

Comment: ок,. благодарю)

Comment: Harry, когда я ввожу Ghdh hshhh, то у меня выводятся символы стоящие до пробела, а остальные игнорируются, разве пробел это не символ?

Comment: Простите, чтение я взял у вас - думал, что читать с помощью `%s` - т.е. **одно слово** - у вас так и задумано. Читайте строку - и все получится: `fgets` или `gets_s` вам в помощь.